# How to change color in a number of different classes that all share the same class with a toggle function

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm coding a simple website with bootstrap 4 and SCSS. I would like to add a toggler which alternates dark and light mode on the web page. However, I cannot change the backgroundcolor of 6 bootstrap cards, footer and the text color of nav links. Can you help me please?

html:

```js
function myFunction() {

  let text = document.getElementById("nox-lumos");
  if (text.innerHTML == 'Nox!') {
    document.getElementById("nox-lumos").innerHTML = 'Lumos!';
  } else if (text.innerHTML == 'Lumos!') {
    document.getElementById("nox-lumos").innerHTML = 'Nox!';
  }


  let page = document.body;
  page.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.rowstyle {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.dark-mode {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: white;
}

.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 28px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#nox-lumos {
    text-decoration: underline 1px;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #fff200;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #e9ecef;
}

.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.picture {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url(../assets/img/mypicture.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center top;
    z-index: 1;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-image: url(../assets/img/amalfi3-2.jpg);
    height: 400px;
    background-position: 0% 85%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.achievements p {
    text-align: center;
}

.achievements h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

#hobbies {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}

.card {
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-img-top {
    width: 40px;
}

.skills i {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#webdev {
    width: 50px;
    filter: invert(23%) sepia(50%) saturate(7357%) hue-rotate(351deg) brightness(88%) contrast(110%);
}

#website {
    width: 50px;
    filter: invert(23%) sepia(69%) saturate(3745%) hue-rotate(212deg) brightness(103%) contrast(108%);
}

#hiking {
    width: 36px;
    filter: invert(33%) sepia(71%) saturate(5507%) hue-rotate(24deg) brightness(97%) contrast(94%);
}

#tech {
    width: 50px;
}

#nutrition {
    width: 50px;
    filter: invert(93%) sepia(94%) saturate(2873%) hue-rotate(320deg) brightness(102%) contrast(101%);
}

#travel {
    width: 50px;
    filter: invert(23%) sepia(69%) saturate(3745%) hue-rotate(212deg) brightness(103%) contrast(108%);
}

footer {
    margin-top: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light col-12 col-md-12" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">Curriculum</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contacts</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i> Github</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i> Linkedin</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope-open"></i> Email</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <label class="switch"> <!--Switch for change colors-->
              <input type="checkbox" checked aria-label="true">
              <span class="slider round" id="button" onclick="myFunction(); myFunction2()"></span>
            </label>
            <span id="nox-lumos">Nox!</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <header class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row picture mx-auto">

      </div>
      <div class="row col-12 col-sm-8 mt-3 mx-auto">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>

      </div>

    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content">
      <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6">
        <h3>Lorem et opossum est</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 mt-1">
        <section class="achievements">
          <h3>Loremlorem:</h3>

          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-danger" style="width: 100%">100%</div>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem et santicum</p>

          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-primary" style="width: 85%">85%</div>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem et frigidus</p>

          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-warning" style="width: 70%">70%</div>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem et mammt</p>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-header text-center">
      <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
        <h3 id="hobbies">Lorem and Lorem:</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col col-12 col-md-4 mt-5">
        <div class="card border-danger text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top mx-auto mt-2" id="webdev" src="assets/svgs/code-solid.svg" alt="coding">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Lorem</h5>
            <p class="card-text text-md-left">LoremLoremLoremLorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-12 col-md-4 mt-5">
        <div class="card border-primary text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top mx-auto mt-2" id="website" src="assets/svgs/display-solid.svg" alt="website">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Lorem</h5>
            <p class="card-text text-md-left">LoremLoremLoremLorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-12 col-md-4 mt-5">
        <div class="card border-warning text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top mx-auto mt-2" id="hiking" src="assets/svgs/person-hiking-solid.svg" alt="person hiking">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Lorem</h5>
            <p class="card-text text-md-left">LoremLoremLoremLorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col col-12 col-md-4 mt-5">
        <div class="card border-danger text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top mx-auto mt-2" id="tech" src="assets/svgs/microchip-solid.svg" alt="microchip">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Lorem</h5>
            <p class="card-text text-md-left">LoremLoremLoremLorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-12 col-md-4 mt-5">
        <div class="card border-primary text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top mx-auto mt-2" id="travel" src="assets/svgs/earth-europe-solid.svg" alt="earth europe">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Lorem</h5>
            <p class="card-text text-md-left">LoremLoremLoremLorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-12 col-md-4 mt-5">
        <div class="card border-warning text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top mx-auto mt-2" id="nutrition" src="assets/svgs/utensils-solid.svg" alt="food utensils">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Lorem</h5>
            <p class="card-text text-md-left">LoremLoremLoremLorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-left">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 mr-0">
          <p>This page was created by me</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you see the error above? There's a big clue. Why are you calling two functions, one of which apparently doesn't exist?

Comment: Protips: Name your functions semantically so it's intuitive what they do. [Vendor prefixes aren't needed for `transition`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition). Use [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than calling functions from your markup.

Comment: Btw @mplungjan, in SCSS, commenting with `//` is actually valid, they just don't appear in the generated css file, `/*  */` do.

Comment: @Bqardi I'm pretty sure that mplungjan knows that. OP doesn't use SCSS or LESS. In any case, as you said yourself, in CSS itself it is not valid.

Comment: Am I reading op's question wrong: "I'm coding a simple website with bootstrap 4 and SCSS."?

Comment: @tacoshy, op had originally used `//` in his post, which mplungian basically said was wrong, and therefore op deleted it. That is the reason for my comment. I could have sworn op was using SCSS.

Comment: We can all delete the // comments since isherwood removed the SCSS and the // -

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set all classes inside `.dark-mode` (this is SCSS/LESS syntax which requires a CSS pre-processor):

```scss
.dark-mode {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: white;

    .card-body {
        background-color: #252525;
        color: white;
    }
    footer {
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

"Normal" CSS solution:

```scss
.dark-mode .card-body {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: white;
}
.dark-mode footer {
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: You should note in your answer that this is not standard CSS, which doesn't allow this kind of nesting. This requires a CSS pre-processor. (sass, less)

Comment: OP uses SCSS, that's why I answered with an SCSS solution.